# Share a class between Windows Universal app and Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I'm developing Windows Store Universal app that uses Azure to store data.
In Visual Studio, there is four projects (Windows, Windows Phone, Shared, Mobile Service). 
In Shared projects there is a class ToDoItem.cs. I want it to be used by all projects to avoid code repetition.

The problem I have is that I cannot add a reference to ToDoNotes.Shared in MobileService project. If I do it the other way round, that is, if I have this class in MobileService and reference it in Windows and Windows Phone projects I hit the same problem.

Is it possible to share this class across all projects?

[image: ToDoItem.cs and four projects]

Comment: Why do you have App.xaml in ToDoNotes.Shared ?
If you have only ToDoItem.cs in a Class Library you should be able to reference it from any project

Answer (score 1):

An Azure project can only reference a classic class library... Universal Apps can only reference portable class libraries so you can not reference the code in this manner... There is one trick left in the arsenal, that is to add the file to both the shared project and the azure project as a link. This will link the file to the azure project Instead of copying the file into the azure project folder directory. See Photo below

The hard part will be trying to use the same code because certain objects have been moved from one namespace to another between universal apps and standard.net such as the XmlDocument, httpclient etc. Your code may have quite a few ifdef statements and this might end up being more trouble than it is worth.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ToDoItem.cs is like a object model, it should be put in a strongly named class library that can be referenced to from any project